# I'm making an API in PHP, but it cannot combine two variables

Tags: php, api, email, sms, phone-number

I am attempting to make an API for an SMS messager in PHP. Everything works and checks out except one thing. It gets the `&carrier` and the `&number` but PHP cannot appear to combine them. Any suggestions? I've attempted debugging it.

The URL is: https://www.swiftresolver.com/sms/api.php?number=number@txt.att.net&from=faded&message=hi&subject=hi&amount=3&carrier=ATT

My whole code:

```
<br>
<br>
<b>Debugging info:</b>
<br>
<?php
$number = trim(strtolower($_GET['number']));
$from = trim(strtolower($_GET['from']));
$message = trim(strtolower($_GET['message']));
$subject = trim(strtolower($_GET['subject']));
$amount = trim(strtolower($_GET['amount']));
$number2 = $number. "@" .$carrier;
print_r($_GET);
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
switch($_GET['carrier']){
    case 'AT&T':
  $carrier = "txt.att.net";
    break;
    case 'Sprint':
  $carrier = "messaging.sprintpcs.com";
    break;
    case 'Verizon':
  $carrier = "vtext.com";
    break;
    case 'T-Mobile':
  $carrier = "tmomail.net";
    break;
    case 'Soufian':
  $carrier = "gin.nl";
    break;
}
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'swiftserver.ddns.net';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'server@swiftserver.ddns.net';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';               // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 25591;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom('fbi@fbi.gov',$from);     //Set who the message is to be sent fr
$mail->AddAddress($number2);               // Name is optional
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = ''.$subject;
$mail->Body    = ''.$message;
if ($amount > 50){
print("You can only send 50 messages at a time. Change the message number to 50 and refresh the page.");
}
else if($amount < 50){
for($i=0; $i < $amount; $i++)
{
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent: ';
   echo '' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
}
echo 'Your message has been sent ' .$amount;
echo ' time(s).';
}
?>
<html>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

I'm having issues with

```
$number2 = $number. "@" .$carrier;
```

Comment: Too much code. Show the *relevant* code to your question.

Comment: @KGW96  
I attempted to put $number2 = #number."@".$carrier; after the switch and it had no affect :/

Comment: Thanks for letting us know it has been fixed. However, questions are kept for posterity here, and are not deleted. Would you let us know in an answer (i.e. not in the question) how it was resolved? It may be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Okay this is what I had to do. In the switch function I just changed AT&T to ATT. Also I would prefer not to give away my code since it was resolved.

Comment: I'll downvote in that case, since leaving a question in a useful state, and offering an answer proper oneself, is the small courtesy expected in return for free assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer on behalf of OP:*

In the switch function, I just changed AT&T to ATT.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but try putting this line `$number2 = $number. "@" .$carrier;` after the switch statement because it  seems like you only declare `$carrier` in the switch. Hope this works.